# Options for comet servers for ruby/ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, comet

What frameworks exist for developing comet applications using Ruby on Rails?

Ideally, whatever options I find should make my life easy when choosing a hosting provider

(I'd rather have something that works with existing web servers, rather than something that requires an exotic comet-enabled web server)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Rainbows!](http://rainbows.rubyforge.org/) - It's based on Unicorn but meant for "sleepy apps and slow clients".

Comment: It doesn't really meet your "I'd rather" statement being that it's its own web server, but you should be able to use it with nginx